# Add to list of objects and overwrite if already present in array

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON object that comes from an API that looks like this:

```
{
  "objectList": [
    {
      "name": "item1",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "name": "item2",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to append items to this. I can do this using `jq`:

```
jq '.objectList += [{"name": "item3", "value": true}]' apiResponse.json
```

However, sometimes I need to add an item with a name attribute that already exists in the response, I need to overwrite it's value with the new one I want to set. For example, I may want to change the value of 'item2' to `false`.

I've written a filter in jq so that I can loop through the `objectList`, but I'm not sure how to compare the two names (the one I want to add, and the name of the item in the current iteration of the loop). Here is my loop filter:

```
jq -r '.objectList[] | [.name]
```

This prints out an array like this:

```
[
  "extendedStatus"
]
[
  "anotherFeature"
]
```

I then tried to add a conditional onto that filter like this:

```
jq -r '.objectList[] | if .name == "item1" then .value == true else .value == false end' apiResponse.json
```

but this simply printed out:

```
true
false
```

Edit - a slightly improved filter:

```
jq -r '.objectList[] | if .name == "item1" then {name: .name, value: true} else {name: .name, value: false} end'
```

This prints out:

```
{
  "name": "item1",
  "value": true
}
{
  "name": "item2",
  "value": false
}
```

This improved filter is better, however I'm still unsure of how to add an item if it doesn't exist in the array (when it's finished looping over it).

One thing to note - this is being done in a bash script, inside a method where I have parameters (the names and values of the items).

Comment: make your question to be more concrete: you've started with `.objectList` array and updating some object by matched `name` attribute. Then, you switched to `.featureFlags` array iterating over existing object list. Emphasize a concrete input structure and a concrete expected result

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I just changed the name and forgot to on the last one. Fixed it now (or will in a few seconds)

Comment: while all new values are hardcoded in your question, elaborate where do a new objects come from and in what form? (the purpose of `.featureFlags[]` is still unclear for me)

Comment: Hi sorry again, where-ever I use `.featureFlags`, it's supposed to be `.objectList`. The new objects come from a shell script that runs the function that does this action, e.g `runMethod(name, value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say besides the main API json file `apiResponse.json`:

```
{
  "objectList": [
    {
      "name": "item1",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "name": "item2",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "name": "item4",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

we have new objects list contained in file `new_objects.dat`:

```
{"name":"item1","value":true}
{"name":"item2","value":false}
{"name":"item3","value":true}
```

---

```
jq --slurpfile new_items new_objects.dat \
     '.objectList |= [ . + $new_items | group_by(.name)[] | add ]' apiResponse.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "objectList": [
    {
      "name": "item1",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "name": "item2",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "name": "item3",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "name": "item4",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` to filter the input. This selects the "item2" elements:

```
.objectList[] | select(.name == "item2")
```

The above will return `null` if you select "item3".  In that case you can use the alternative operator `//` to define a default value:

```
(.objectList[] | select(.name == "itemX")) // {"name": "item3", "value": null}
```

The above will always return an object, which can be modified by setting "value" to `false`:

```
((.objectList[] | select(.name == "itemX")) // {"name": "item3", "value": null}) | .value = false
```

In order to get a complete list, you have to add those elements which do not match with another select.

```
.objectList[] | select(.name != "itemX")
```

The two lists can be joined using a comma and square brackets and the result can be put into a new object.

```
[
  (((.objectList[] | select(.name == "itemX")) // {"name": "item3", "value": null}) | .value = false)
  ,
  (.objectList[] | select(.name != "itemX"))
] |
{"objectList": .}
```